# Как отменить все axios запросы при переходе на другой компонент (страницу)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios

у меня есть данный код, который циклом запрашивает фотографии в base64 с сервера по названиям, (которые я аналогично получил ранее) для слайдера фотографий на странице проекта:

```
const fetchPhoto = async () => {
        for (let i = 0; i < project.photo.length; i++) {
            const image = {
                title: project.name,
                name: project.photo[i],
            }
            axios.get(`/image/${image.title}/${image.name}`).then(async ({data}) => {
                photoBase64[i] = data;
                setPhotoBase64({...photoBase64});
            });
        }
    }
    fetchPhoto();
```

Если у пользователя будет низкая интернет-скорость, и он откроет какой-то проект (откроет компонент "проект"), закроет его (перейдет в компонент "все проекты") и откроет другой, то ему придется ждать, пока загрузятся фотографии прошлого проекта, потом начнется загрузка для текущего проекта. Как мне отменить запросы, если я перехожу из компонента "проект" в какой-либо другой ?

Comment: [Прерываение выполнения ajax](https://axios-http.com/ru/docs/cancellation) - думаю это то, что вам надо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Как мне отменить запросы, если я перехожу из компонента "проект" в какой-либо другой ?

Начиная с версии `v0.22.0` Axios поддерживает `AbortController` для отмены запросов через `fetch API`:

```
// объявляем контроллер
const controller = new AbortController();

axios.get('/foo/bar', {
   // устанавливаем связь с контроллером
   signal: controller.signal
}).then(function(response) {
   //...
});
// отмена запроса
controller.abort()
```

Более подробнее в этой статье
https://axios-http.com/ru/docs/cancellation

Comment: Пробовал использовать AbortController, однако как мне организовать создание контроллера и отмену запросов ? Мне нужно отменить запрос при открытии другой страницы, соответственно нужно вызвать controller.abort() там, но как правильно его туда передать и где его изначально инициализировать? При этом, при переходе обратно на страницу проекта, необходимо, чтобы запросы вновь отправлялись. Спасибо за ответ

Comment: @Alastorial, как видно из моего примера создание контроллера делается до запуска запроса, а не перед его удалением. Для удаления запрос уже нужно запускать с привязкой к контроллеру. Далее нужно контролировать события приводящие к переходу на новую страницу и там, в событиях, давать команду на прекращение запросов.

Comment: Я решил иначе задачу. Запросы происходят в useEffect(), где можно указать return с функцией, где и вызвать abort(). return срабатывает при прекращении рендера компонента

Comment: @Alastorial, и в чем тут "иначе"? :)

Comment: да, вы правы, по сути вышло, как вы и описали, благодарю